# How can I include user profile's images/logos on django comments

Tags: django, comments

I've posted this on django-users but haven't received a reply!

So I have my own profile objects for users (subclass of User). One of the fields is imagefield, which is (obviously) used for users to upload their logo/thumbnail.

The question is how I can include this on their comments?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subclassing User is not recommended in Django. Instead, create a separate profile model.

Let's assume you have your app, *foo*.

In foo's *models.py*, add:

```
class FooUserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
   user_image = models.ImageField()
```

Then, in your *settings.py*, add:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'foo.FooUserProfile'
```

Now, whenever you have a user object, you can get its profile object with the get_profile() function. In your case, in the template you could add:

```
<img src="{{ comment.user.get_profile.user_image }}"/>
```

A caveat: you will need to create a FooUserProfile and associate it with your User any time you create new User.

You can read more in the Django documentation, [Storing additional information about users](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) or in the article [Django tips: extending the User model](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/)