# Linking Django comments with django users

Tags: django, user-profile, django-comments, django-users

I am using Django in built comments for allowing users to comment on my posts. I have also customized the app to do the following thing

- Registered users will see just the text area for comments
- Unregistered users will see the whole form

Although the whole thing is working fine, I do not understand how can I link the user comment to the user's profile. I want to make the comment name clickable such that it takes you to the user's profile who posted that comment.

However in case of unregistered users I just want to display the name as it. Where and how do I have to make the changes in the comments form, such that it links it with the current user.

Comment: Post code you has, User, UserProfile and Coment Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer: [How can I include user profile's images/logos on django comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492987/how-can-i-include-user-profiles-images-logos-on-django-comments/493076#493076)

`comment.user` or `comment.user.get_profile`, if you use `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`, should give you the user who posted the comment.

Now you can fetch all the data you need:

```
<a href="{{ comment.user.get_profile.get_absolute_url }}">
  {{ comment.user.get_profile.firstname }}
</a>
```